# Function/Code in R that is a class() variant of colnames()

Tags: r, function, class, analytics, information-retrieval

I am comparing multiple data frames in R, each with multiple columns that should have the same name and the same data type. I know how to simply code for a TRUE/FALSE result in checking for matching column names, and I have a method for checking matching column data types, but the data types method requires exponentially longer code than the column names method and I want a simpler solution.

I can verify column names as matching with (code_1):

```
all(c(
  all(colnames(df_1)==colnames(df_2)),
  all(colnames(df_1)==colnames(df_3))
))
```

But to verify data types as matching, this is the best I could come up with (code_2):

```
all(c(
  all(c(
    class(df_1$column_1)==class(df_2$column_1),
    class(df_1$column_2)==class(df_2$column_2)
  )),
  all(c(
    class(df_1$column_1)==class(df_3$column_1),
    class(df_1$column_2)==class(df_3$column_2)
  ))
))
```

Ideally, I would want something like this that can do the equivalent of code_2 (code_3):

```
all(c(
  all(xyzfunction(df_1)==xyzfunction(df_2)),
  all(xyzfunction(df_1)==xyzfunction(df_3))
))
```

I don't know if such an "xyzfunction" exists though and can't find such a function with my research. Do any of you know of such a function or a simpler way to write code_2 when you have many more data frames and columns per data frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `==` for comparing the return from `class`, since the length of its return is variable:

```r
class(1)
# [1] "numeric"
class(Sys.time())
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
class(ggplot2::diamonds)
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

It should be safe-enough to use `identical`, though.

```r
xyzfunction <- function(x, y) {
  if (!identical(sort(names(x)), sort(names(y)))) return(FALSE)
  nms <- names(x)
  return(identical(lapply(.subset(x, nms), class), lapply(.subset(y, nms), class)))
}
```

I use `.subset` instead of `x[nms]` since `x[nms]` works with `data.frame` and `tbl_df` but not with `data.table`, and `subset` itself is intended more for interactive use, not programmatic unsupervised use like this.